# Do not stop the program when communication is lost with the FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a program that connects to an FTP server, but I have a problem that when the connection is lost the program STOP.

what I want is that if I lose the connection to the server the program continue trying to connect to the server,  and when connecting continue operating normally

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("...");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (user,pass);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

How I can do?

Thanks for all!

Comment: You must be doing something else, because your code *shouldn't* currently end the program if it fails. Perhaps you just have an uncaught exception that isn't showing up when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your code in a try-catch block.